# Error suppression in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to suppress errors in **SQL** (MySQL and such, NO PHP)?

For **EXAMPLE** i would like to suppress error at this line:

```
drop user 'Username'@'localhost';
```

Is it possible?

Comment: isn't it better to avoid error than suppress?

Comment: Why do you want to suppress errors?  That's usually a bad practice.  It's usually better to catch/fix errors or check first to prevent them than to just blindly run code and ignore the error.

Comment: Why not solving it instead of giving low-level tips?